# How to handle sync of relationships with RestKit (Offline support)

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, synchronization

I wrote a sync engine with the use of RestKit and CoreData. The problem right now I have is how I can handle the sync of a relationship if both of the object has not been synced and therefor don't have a server assigned ID. I do have the CoreData relationship set. I don't need an exact solution how I should do it but a overall concept how to handle that would be awesome.

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: So create 2 objects locally, with relationship between, then how to send these to the server (and get back server assigned ids for them)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to create the objects on the server first, get the ids, and then set the relationship.

Another option would be to use uuids for your objects, and create them client side.

Answer (score 0):

To support offline mode the best is to create Objects on client side and assign them Unique ID, create their relationships at client and then Sync them back to server. The server can then store those newly created objects in DB.

Only you need to consider weather you can modify/assign ID to objects in DB, i-e you can assign ID to Mongo DB instances and save back.